# Несколько окон. Qt Widgets

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Как в Qt Widgets сделать переход между окнами?

Точней организовать такую структуру, которая при нажатии кнопки, к примеру, создавало другое окно, а это закрывало и в памяти прошлое окно не висело? Использовал `stackedwidgets` для этого, но там я как понял будет в памяти висеть все другие окна, хотелось бы обойтись без этого.

Comment: оно ж моргать будет. лучше разберись с QStackedWidget. Там есть remove.  после добавления нового старый вынимай из стека и удаляй

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
void MyClass::OnButtonClicked()
{
    FirstWindow->close();
    FirstWindow->deleteLater();
    FirstWindow = nullptr;

    SecondWindow = new MyWindow();        
    SecondWindow->show();
}
```

Здесь `FirstWindow->close()` должна внутри [вызвать QWindow::destroy()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#close) и ресурсы нативной оконной подсистемы освободятся. Вызов [FirstWindow->deleteLater()](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) удалит сам `QObject` на следующем цикле обработки сообщений. Наконец все ресурсы освобождены поэтому указатель `FirstWindow` зануляется.

Далее просто создается новое окно, при этом родителем у него будет глобальный `QApplication`. Если нужен другой родитель, то нужно его подставить в конструктор.

Comment: Появилась ошибка: " ‘r’ was not declared in this scope " при попытке объявить в динамической памяти. И строку с nullptr он тоже бракует, так как lvalue required as left operand of assignment.  
Вот код:  
void Window::on_pushButton_clicked()   
{  
    this->close();  
    this->deleteLater();  
    this = nullptr;  
      
    r = new Form();  
    r->show();    
}

Comment: @ДаниилАгеев переменную `r` надо объявить в области видимости, т.е. задать ей тип. Ругань на `nullptr` уйдет при включении поддержки c++11 компилятором.